mssql connection with flowise
I am running flowise in my localhost. I did install mssql package, but still getting this error:

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to mssql.us.umbhost.net:1433 -
self-signed certificate

although with code it work, any guidance?
enter image description here
i tried adding ?trustServerCertificate=true&encrypt:false  in my conn str, but still same.

Since you are trying to use mssql+pymssql:// URLs with the SqlDatabaseChain, how have you configured the server entry in /etc/freetds.conf? There are lots of options available.

First, clone and set up Flowise. Then, navigate to the folder directory Flowise\packages\server. Locate the env.example file and open it. On the 31st line, remove the "#" and add mssql. rename file name to env (remove .example) After making this change,  in console(flowise directory) pnpm install mssql ,build and relaunch Flowise.enter image description here
